# Как правильно реализовать метод RemoveFromRoleAsync (IUserRoleStore )?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

Добрый день.
я пытаюсь реализовать самостоятельно (в учебных целях), свой UserStore и Manager в Identity.
И при реализации метода **RemoveFromRoleAsync**, я не могу понять как его правильно реализовать.
Существует таблица **AspNetUserRoles**, которая связывает пользователей и их роли.
в **ApplicationDbContext** нет этой сущности, в какую сторону смотреть? 
И еще вопрос а есть ли исходники стандартной реализации UserStore ?

Comment: Взгляните на этот класс https://github.com/stuartleeks/leeksnet.AspNet.Identity.TableStorage/blob/master/leeksnet.AspNet.Identity.TableStorage/UserStore.cs

Comment: @Vardan Vardanyan я не понял один момент он там делает такую вещь user.Roles.Remove(role) , НО ведь role это string, а метод Remove принимает IdentityUserRole

Comment: еще раз посмотрите и увидите что второй параметер это **string role** !  
  
`public async Task RemoveFromRoleAsync(TUser user,string role)`

Comment: да это параметр метода RemoveFromRoleAsync, но я имею ввиду ,что user.Roles.Remove(role), метод Remove принимает  IdentityUserRole